# Can I alternate between gnome and xfce desktop env if both are chosen during installation.

Tags: debian, gnome, xfce, debian-installer

I installed Debian Jessie 8 with Gnome and xfce desktop environment but when the operating system boots it goes straight into the xfce environment. I thought it would load into the first option, which is gnome and then if you wanted to go into xfce you would have to type a command in terminal that allows you to switch into xfce. Is it possible to alternate between the two now it only boots into xfce?

Comment: Do you not have an option to choose from your login greeter? For example, selecting your user from gdm allows you to pick your desktop before you submit your password.

Comment: I do but it says  Default Session and Xsession not Gnome @KalvinLee